# Is there a way to have a build log when running 'make'?

Tags: compiling, io-redirection, make

I need/want to have the whole build log when compiling a tool. The tool uses `autotools`.

I tried the most obvious way `$ make > make.txt` but that just gave the very end of the build to `make.txt` when I wanted to have the whole build `log`. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run `make` as follow:

```
 make 2>&1 | tee make.txt
```